# Rehydration of store not working with redux-persist in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

Rehydration of redux-persist is not working for an unknown reason. Here is my config:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['user'],
};

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  let reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  let composeEnhancers = compose;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window === 'object') {
    if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) {
      composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        trace: true,
      });
    }

    if (window.__SAGA_MONITOR_EXTENSION__) {
      reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {
        sagaMonitor: window.__SAGA_MONITOR_EXTENSION__,
      };
    }
  }

  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
  const {run: runSaga} = sagaMiddleware;

  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, thunkMiddleware];

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga,
    }),
  ];

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer());

  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return {store, persistor};
}
```

Heere is the reducer:

```
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...injectedReducers,
    locale: localeReducer,
    user: userReducer,
  });
}
```

Here is how the App renderer function:

```
const initialState = {};
const {store, persistor} = configureStore(initialState);

const renderApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

When app launches:
[image]

After user pressed login button:
[image]

After app was closed and reopened:
[image]

Can anyone help please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately :(

Comment: In my case, the problem was somewhere within my reducers. It helps to blacklist your reducers and start adding them one by one, until the problem resurfaces. This way I was able to say which reducer and which part of it misbehaves. Using config `debug: true` helps too: if you don't see rehydration message at the startup, something went wrong.